# Vpython 3D Box+Text combination

Tags: python, vpython

I am new to Python/Vpython and would appreciate some guidance. What is the best means to create a vpython box (or 3D rectangle, etc..) with a unique text string on each face of the box such that when the box rotates, the text will rotate as well.

A simple way to envision this program would be similar to a dice roll, whereby the number of dots on the side changes as the dice rotates. Rather than dots, my cube ("dice") will have words instead of dots.

Vpython makes it quite simple to build the box, but there is no text attribute for a box.  I've been tinkering about with extrusion, but doesn't seem to be the solution here.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

FYI: I resolved this myself by creating a composite object (a box and several text objects) within a frame, then spinning the frame.